# What's the output of the program?

Tags: c

I saw the following code in http://indiabix.com/
Can anyone explain the code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
   float a=5.375;
   char *p;
   int i;
   p = (char*)&a;

   for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
   {
         printf("%02x\n", (unsigned char)p[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And the result is

> 00 00 AC 40

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program reinterprets the memory where a float is stored. Depending on the size of destination (float here), its representation (Assume [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)), and [machine endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) it may give different outputs.

In this case, it appears machine is little endian and float representation is IEEE754.

You can use [this](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) online tool to visualize the float reprentation in binary.

```
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Input       | 5.375                                                     |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Binary32    | 40 AC 00 00                                               |
+--------+----+-----+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| Status | Sign [1] | Exponent [8]  | Significand [23]                    |
+--------+----------+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| Normal |   0 (+)  | 10000001 (+2) | 1.01011000000000000000000 (1.34375) |
+--------+----------+---------------+-------------------------------------+
```

---

Loosely related topic: [Strict aliasing rule.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)